# Subtract array values of Object

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I subtract Cell[3,5] from Cell[5,4]?? I have a cell Object which creates a 2D array and set warrior Object in it.
I tried this but it didnot work

```
Cell[,] cells = new Cell[6,6];
cells[3, 5] = new Cell(warrior);
cells[5,4] = new Cell(warrior);

...

int x1 = cells[3, 5].x - cells[5, 4].x;
int x2 = cells[3, 5].y - cells[5, 4].y;
Console.WriteLine(x1);
Console.WriteLine(x2);
```

My Cell class is like this:

> ```
> public class Cell
> {
>     public int _x;
>     public int _y;
>     public Warrior _warrior; 
> }
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by, `I tried this but id didnot work?` Could you explain more?

Comment: Do you have a constructor of type `Cell(Warrior warrior)?`?

Comment: public Cell(Warrior getWarrior)
        { 
            this._warrior = getWarrior;
        }  I am setting warrior like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Write a sample code try like this..

```
 Warrior warrior = new Warrior(25,24);
        Warrior warrior1 = new Warrior(20,20);

        Cell[,] cells = new Cell[6, 6];
        cells[3, 5] = new Cell(warrior);
        cells[5, 4] = new Cell(warrior1);

        int x1 = cells[3, 5]._x - cells[5, 4]._x;
        int x2 = cells[3, 5]._y - cells[5, 4]._y;
        Console.WriteLine(x1);
        Console.WriteLine(x2);

 public class Cell
{
    public Cell(Warrior warrior)
    {
        _x = warrior.x;
        _y = warrior.y;
    }

    public int _x;
    public int _y;
    public Warrior _warrior;
}

public class Warrior
{
    public Warrior(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int x;

    public int y;
}
```

> OutPut : 5 4

Comment: This works . Now I want to get the warrior that has been set to cells[3,5]. I did cells[3,5]._warrior but it does not return anything

Comment: I dont understand what you are exactly trying to say, Can you please elobrate.. or give some example

Comment: I added public Cell(Warrior warrior)
    {
        _x = warrior.x;
        _y = warrior.y; _warrior = warrior
    } and this works now for getting warrior set...thanks for quick reply